# s3cmd list of contents - only filenames - perl one liner?

Tags: perl, s3cmd

Currently I'm using `s3cmd ls s3://location/ > file.txt` to get a list of contents of my s3 bucket and save on a txt. However the above returns dates, filesizes paths and filenames.

for example:

```
2011-10-18 08:52      6148   s3://location//picture_1.jpg
```

I only need the filenames of the s3 bucket - so on the above example I only need `picture_1.jpg`.
Any suggestions?

Could this be done with a Perl one liner maybe after the initial export?

Comment: In case you didn't already know, there are CPAN modules to facilitate programmatic access to S3, e.g. Net::Amazon::S3. So instead of calling out to s3cmd, you could just call out the relevant method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File::Listing](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aListing) does not support this format because the designers of this listing format were stupid enough to not simply reuse an existing one. Let's parse it manually instead.

```
use URI;
my @ls = (
    "2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_1.jpg\n",
    "2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_2.jpg\n",
    "2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_3.jpg\n",
);

for my $line (@ls) {
    chomp $line;
    my $basename = (URI->new((split q( ), $line)[-1])->path_segments)[-1];
}

__END__
picture_1.jpg
picture_2.jpg
picture_3.jpg
```

---

As oneliner:

```
perl -mURI -lne 'print ((URI->new((split q( ), $line)[-1])->path_segments)[-1])' < input
```

Answer (score 5):

Use awk:

```
s3cmd ls s3://location/ | awk '{ print $4 }' > file.txt
```

If you have filenames with spaces, try:

```
s3cmd ls s3://location/ | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure a specific module is the safer option, but if the data is reliable, you can get away with a one-liner:

Assuming the input is:

```
2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_1.jpg
2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_2.jpg
2011-10-18 08:52 6148 s3://location//picture_3.jpg
...
```

The one-liner:

```
perl -lnwe 'print for m#(?<=//)([^/]+)$#'
```

- `-l` `chomp`s the input, and adds newline to end of `print` statements
- `-n` adds a `while(<>)` loop around the script
- `(?<=//)` lookbehind assertion finds a double slash
- ...followed by non-slashes to the end of the line
- The `for` loop assures us that non-matches are not printed.

The benefit of the `-n` option is that this one-liner may be used in a pipe, or on a file.

```
command | perl -lnwe '...'
perl -lnwe '...' filename
```